# Extract data from API in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

```
class Rnn extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
 x:[]
}
}

componentWillMount(){
 var api={
 getroverss(){
 var url="https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent";
 return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
}
},
 api.getrovers().then((res) =>{
 this.setState({ x: res
 })
 });
 }
 render(){
 var xx=this.state.x;
 console.table(xx);
 return (
  <h1>print data</h1>
  );
 }}
```

I have been using this api get data from it. I have managed to ouput the data on console. How do I get(ouput/print) the data on my webpage? (I want to use fetch method only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the items and render them to the DOM

```
{xx.map((x, idx) => {<div key={idx}> {x.username} </div> })}
```

So, at your discretion, you can choose how to format other data inside `xx`. Let me add that you might prefer `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`. See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899116/what-is-the-difference-between-componentwillmount-and-componentdidmount-in-react)

Comment: where should i add these, in return statement?

Comment: @sugandhgoyal Correct!