# What is the difference between ComponentWillMount and ComponentDidMount in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

Need to understand about the difference between these two func in ReactJs. 
ComponentWillMount(){} VS ComponentDidMount(){}

Comment: The former is invoked **right before** the component will mount to the DOM. The latter **right after**. This is suggested by their names... *will* and *did*.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between componentWillMount and componentDidMount in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899116/what-is-the-difference-between-componentwillmount-and-componentdidmount-in-react)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

componentWillMount() gets called before first render whereas componentDidMount() gets called after first render. Both of these components gets called only once

Please note that componentWillMount() is deprecated in latest React version v16

Comment: Constructer and ComponentWillMount are same or not?

Comment: constructor is basically to initialise state and do function bindings. componentWillMount does almost same but we don’t use this method much. Because we do all initialisations in constructor and this is recommended over componentWillMount

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Most discussed topic still explaining my understanding. 
`ComponentWillMount` executes before render as name suggest
`ComponentAfterMount` executes before render once component gets rendered on screen as name suggest.

look at console logs in example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
     console.log("console loging before component will mount");
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     console.log("console loging after mounting component");
  }
  render(){
    console.log("rendering component")
    return(
     <div> component</div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: You are saying that ComponentWillMount execute just before rendering component and ComponentDidMount execute just after rendering component. right?

Comment: Yes componentDidMount executes after component renders completely

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

## **Difference**

***componentDidMount()***

- invoked immediately after a component is mounted.
- it's gets called only once per mounting so good place for network requests and subscriptions.
- do not assign state here or call setState.

***componentWillMount()***

- invoked just before mounting occurs.
- the only method which is called on server-rendering
- should avoid using this ( it is a legacy method and will be removed in upcoming react version ).

You should avoid using *componentWillMount* and use componentDidMount and constructor instead
Please check the official [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) for more info

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.